# C++: Resolve Constructor Initializer List Dependencies with RAII

Tags: c++, constructor, raii

One particularly tricky thing to setup safely is GLX. The problem is that quite a few resources must be allocated, and deallocated in the correct order in case of errors at any point during the initialization.

Here is what I wrote in C (only the relevant parts).

```
int gfx_init(struct gfx *g)
{
    int vis_attriblist[] = { GLX_RGBA, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None };
    XSetWindowAttributes wa;
    XVisualInfo *vis_info;
    int r = 0;

    g->xdpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (g->xdpy == NULL) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("Could not open X Display");
            goto xopendisplay_failed;
    }

    vis_info = glXChooseVisual(g->xdpy, DefaultScreen(g->xdpy),
                               vis_attriblist);
    if (vis_info == NULL) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("Couldn't get an RGBA, double-buffered visual"
                      " (GLX available?)\n");
            goto glxchoosevisual_failed;
    }

    g->xcolormap = XCreateColormap(g->xdpy, DefaultRootWindow(g->xdpy),
                                   vis_info->visual, AllocNone);
    if (gfx_has_xerror(g) /* Checks if there are errors
                             by flushing Xlib's protocol buffer
                             with a custom error handler set.
                             Not included here */) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("Failed to create colormap");
            goto xcreatecolormap_failed;
    }

    wa.colormap = g->xcolormap;
    wa.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask | VisibilityChangeMask;

    g->xwindow = XCreateWindow(g->xdpy, DefaultRootWindow(g->xdpy),
                               0,0,1280,1024, 0, vis_info->depth,
                               InputOutput, vis_info->visual, CWColormap |
                               CWEventMask, &wa);
    if (gfx_has_xerror(g)) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("Failed to create X11 Window");
            goto xcreatewindow_failed;
    }

    g->glxctx = glXCreateContext(g->xdpy, vis_info, NULL, True);
    if (g->glxctx == NULL) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("Failed to create GLX context");
            goto glxcreatecontext_failed;
    }

    if (glXMakeCurrent(g->xdpy, g->xwindow, g->glxctx) == False) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("Failed to make context current");
            goto glxmakecurrent_failed;
    }

    g->xa_wmdeletewindow = XInternAtom(g->xdpy, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    if (gfx_has_xerror(g)) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("XInternAtom failed");
            goto xinternatom_failed;
    }

    XSetWMProtocols(g->xdpy, g->xwindow, &g->xa_wmdeletewindow, 1);
    if (gfx_has_xerror(g)) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("XSetWMProtocols failed");
            goto xsetwmprotocols_failed;
    }

    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glColor4f(0,0,0,1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            r = -1;
            LOG_ERROR("There have been GL errors");
            goto gotglerror;
    }

    XMapWindow(g->xdpy, g->xwindow);
    XFlush(g->xdpy);

    if (r < 0) {
gotglerror:
xsetwmprotocols_failed:
xinternatom_failed:
            glXMakeCurrent(g->xdpy, None, NULL);
glxmakecurrent_failed:
            glXDestroyContext(g->xdpy, g->glxctx);
glxcreatecontext_failed:
            XDestroyWindow(g->xdpy, g->xwindow);
xcreatewindow_failed:
            XFreeColormap(g->xdpy, g->xcolormap);
    }

xcreatecolormap_failed:
    /* This is a local resource which must be destroyed
       in case of success as well */
    XFree(vis_info);

    if (r < 0) {
glxchoosevisual_failed:
            XCloseDisplay(g->xdpy);
    }

xopendisplay_failed:
    return r;
}
```

Actually I'm quite happy with it. I think it's good C style. The only problem being that for a `gfx_destroy` function, the code for `gfx_init`'s deallocation part must be sort of duplicated, but that's very straightforward.

What I would like to know is how to do this initialization in good RAII C++ style. In particular, there is a dependency between the member allocations, and an imaginary RAII `class Gfx`'s constructor should initialize in the correct order, or throw an exception and guarantee that the initial constructed part is torn down again.

So the natural progression is to write short wrappers for the allocated types. E.g.

```
struct MyDisplay {
    Display *dpy;
    MyDisplay() : dpy(XOpenDisplay(NULL)) { if (!dpy) throw "XOpenDisplay()"; }
    ~MyDisplay() { XCloseDisplay(dpy); }
};
struct MyXVisualInfo {
    XVisualInfo *info;
    static int vis_attriblist[] = { GLX_RGBA, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None };
    MyXVisualInfo(Display *dpy)
            : info(glXChooseVisual(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), vis_attriblist) {
        if (!info)
            throw "glXChooseVisual()";
   }
   ~MyXVisualInfo() {
       XFree(info);
   }
};
```

And the `Gfx` class:

```
class Gfx {
    MyDisplay mydpy_;
    MyXVisualInfo myinfo_;
    /* ... */
public:
    Gfx::Gfx() : mydpy_(), myinfo_(mydpy_.dpy) /* , ... */ {}
};
```

<strike>But at this point we have a problem: `myinfo_(mydpy.dpy)` actually [hands an undefined value to the MyXVisualInfo constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286720/1073695). Is this is a showstopper for RAII class members?</strike> *(this is not true, see @MarkB's answer*)

Also, if the constructor needs to allocate temporary resources, as is actually the case for `myinfo_` which I would like to not store inside the class, I think there is no way to avoid entering the constructor body, *and assigning to the members from there*, using resources local to the constructor body. This means members will undergo an additional construction and deconstruction which is a no-go as there are sideeffects involved.

The only thing I can think of is using `unique_ptr`:

```
class Gfx {
    unique_ptr<MyDisplay> mydpy_;
    unique_ptr<MyColormap> mycolormap_;
    /* ... */
public:
    Gfx() {
        mydpy_.reset(new MyDisplay());

        MyXVisualInfo myinfo(dpy);

        mycolormap_.reset(new MyXColormap(mydpy_->dpy,
                                          DefaultRootWindow(mydpy_->dpy),
                                          myinfo->info, AllocNone));
    }
};
```

Now this is obviously overengineered and has become a kludge to maintain. Also introducing unique_ptr which has unneeded overhead is not nice.

Isn't there a clean approach that would do what the C version does in a clean RAII manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` can be used with a custom deleter. Example:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> mem (static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int))), free);
```

or with a lambda:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> mem (new int(), [](int* foobar) {
    std::cout << "I am a deleter" << std::endl;
    delete foobar;
});
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need. For the cases where I don't have pointers but POD structs, I had already thought of subclassing the POD structs to add the RAII deletion. Your answer shows how to extend this idea to pointers: The construct is semantically a subclass to the contained pointers.

Comment: I see smart pointers more like outsourcing the responsibility of memory management to something that is good at it. Raw pointers are actually hard, if not sometimes inhuman, to get correct when C++ exceptions are nearby.

Comment: Addendum for the learning (like me): I'm personally not a fan of shared_ptr as it makes destruction less explicit and less deterministic, which is a drawback especially for side effecting dtors. I will go for unique_ptr instead. Usage is also very convenient using `&*`: `unique_ptr<Display, mydeleter> dpy(XOpenDisplay(NULL)); glxChooseVisual(&*dpy, ...`

Answer (score 2):

What leads you to the conclusion that `myinfo(mydpy.dpy)` will have undefined behavior? The SO question you linked *is not* the same scenario you have in your sample code. Note that in your case you list the members in the class definition in the order you want them initialized so there is no undefined behavior.

Typically if you feel that you can't do something you need in the initialized list and need to use the constructor body you can alternately factor out code into a function and use the return value from that in the initializer list but I'm having a really hard time understanding what you mean after `Also, if the constructor needs to allocate temporary resources` so I can't give you a better answer than that.

Comment: The example for `temporary resources` is `vis_info` from the C version.

Comment: If I factor out to static functions and use the return value in the initializer list, this will still deconstruct/construct unless I employ move semantics and add conditional teardown which is very implementation-heavy. I'd rather have another approach.

Comment: +1: Thanks for correcting me with the order part-- I totally got that other SO post wrong.